# How to import specific error from boto?

Tags: boto3

I am getting this exception (printing the class for debugging) when running my code:

```
An error occurred (DBInstanceNotFound) when calling the DescribeDBInstances operation: DBInstance <instance name> not found.
<class 'botocore.errorfactory.DBInstanceNotFoundFault'>
```

I would like to handle the exception properly like this:

```
from botocore.exceptions import DBInstanceNotFoundFault
from botocore.errorfactory import DBInstanceNotFoundFault
try:
    <fetch info about db instance>
except DBInstanceNotFoundFault as e:
    <handle error>
```

Unfortunately *DBInstanceNotFoundFault* does neither exist in *botocore.exceptions* nor in *botocore.errorfactory*.
I've cloned [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) as well as [botocore](https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/develop/botocore) and [grep'd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) for *DBInstanceNotFoundFault* but just can't find it.

**How can I import it?**

Comment: Did you first try to use the general `try: except:` to capture and pinpoint the exception error you need?

Comment: I did a `print(e.__class__)` inside a `except Exception as e:` to get it, you can see the result in the first code block.

Comment: You should use `print(type(e))` to get the exception instance,  `print(e.args)` for arguments

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For boto3 exceptions, you don't actually import the error - rather you access it through the client. Check this out: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1195#issuecomment-317108970

```
import boto3
rds = boto3.client('rds')
try:
    ...
except rds.exceptions.DBInstanceNotFoundFault:
    ...
```

Comment: Can I use the `except rds.exceptions.DBInstanceNotFoundFault as e` syntax?

Comment: @AnthonyKong Yes you can use it.

Comment: It would be nice to have normal imports...